# Putting NewLine in writing CSV documents Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file, csv, file-read

I am trying to write data calculated by my perl script into a csv file which will be repeatedly opened and input to. I have encountered two issues. One, the CSV created ocupies a single row, adding each new field to a new column. The seccond is that the CSV file once created does not succesfully close so I am unable to reopen and edit it by running the script again. 
the code that I am using is this:

```
push my @rows, ["Entries Missing from English doc:"," " , "Entries Missing  from French doc:"];
push @rows, ["$englishUnincluded[0]", " ", "$frenchUnincluded[0]"];
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({binary=>1}) or die "cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open my $csvFile, ">:encoding(utf8)", "telt.csv" or die "telt.csv: $!";
$csv->column_names(@{$rows[0]});
$csv->print($csvFile, $_) for @rows;
close $csvFile or die "teet.csv: didnt close at all";
```

I have also tried using consecutive print statements rather than the `$csv->print(..) for @rows;` I previously had statments looking like

`$field_vals = ["$val", "something", " "];
$csv->print($csvFile, $field_vals);` and reloaded all the values into field vals and printed them as lines to the CSV but had the same two issues continuously.

** note that CSV not closing issue goes away if only one line is printed. 
Also, script does not print the "or die" message on not closing the file properly.

thank you in advance for any help you provide!

Comment: You can go to a different approach and write to a CSV by just `print`ing to `$csvfile` the values you want delimited by commas and `print $csvfile "\n"` at the end of a line

Answer (score 4):

You've forgotten to declared end of line:

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({binary=>1, eol => $/}) or die "cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
#                           here __^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixed my line issue, It does not however solve my permission issue, The file is stil not closing properly. I am getting the same `tegt.csv: Permission denied at perlScript.pl line 97 #the open line`

Comment: @BrendanL.: Add the reason why the file isn't closed, `$!` in the die after the close.

Comment: .: I actually do not get a did not close message on the close or die, which is why I am so confused by this issue. It does not print the or die message and does not end the program after the close or die. Ie: I can print things after the statement and run subfunctions and other such things.

Comment: @BrendanL.: You've said before `The file is stil not closing properly`, that's why I asked about the message on close.  What are the permissions of the file? Are you running the script under the same user account?

Comment: the file is being created by the script and then it is expected to be oppenned again by the same script. but on the seccond run of the script I get that errror with the permissions. also the File cannot be deleted from my text editor but only from file explorer

Comment: May be this link will help you: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1121545